# Arraylist in parcelable object

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable, typed

I have seen many parcelable examples so far, but for some reason I can't get it to work when it gets a bit more complex.
I have a Movie object, which implements Parcelable. This book object contains some properties, such as ArrayLists.
Running my app results in a NullPointerException when executing the ReadTypedList ! I'm really out of ideas here

```
public class Movie implements Parcelable{
   private int id;
   private List<Review> reviews
   private List<String> authors;

   public Movie () {
      reviews = new ArrayList<Review>();
      authors = new ArrayList<String>();
   }

   public Movie (Parcel in) {
      readFromParcel(in);
   }

   /* getters and setters excluded from code here */

   public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

      dest.writeInt(id);
      dest.writeList(reviews);
      dest.writeStringList(authors);
   }

   public static final Parcelable.Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Movie>() {

      public MoviecreateFromParcel(Parcel source) {
         return new Movie(source);
      }

      public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
         return new Movie[size];
      }

   };

   /*
    * Constructor calls read to create object
    */
   private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
      this.id = in.readInt();
      in.readTypedList(reviews, Review.CREATOR); /* NULLPOINTER HERE */
      in.readStringList(authors);
   }
}
```

The Review class:

```
    public class Review implements Parcelable {
   private int id;
   private String content;

   public Review() {

   }

   public Review(Parcel in) {
      readFromParcel(in);
   }

   public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
      dest.writeInt(id);
      dest.writeString(content);
   }

   public static final Creator<Review> CREATOR = new Creator<Review>() {

      public Review createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
         return new Review(source);
      }

      public Review[] newArray(int size) {
         return new Review[size];
      }
   };

   private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
      this.id = in.readInt();
      this.content = in.readString();
   }

}
```

I would be very grateful if someone could just get me on the right track, I have spend quite a bit of time searching for this one !

Thanks in adnvance
Wesley

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`reviews` and `authors` are both null.  You should first initialize the ArrayList.  One way to do this is chain the constructor:

```
public Movie (Parcel in) {
   this();
   readFromParcel(in); 
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUUUUUCH, I wasted 2 days on this :-).

Answer (score 15):

From the javadocs for `readTypedList`:

> Read into the given List items containing a particular object type
>   that were written with `writeTypedList(List)`

at the current `dataPosition()`. The list must have previously been written via `writeTypedList(List)` with the same object type.

You wrote them with a plain

```
dest.writeList(reviews);
```

Comment: Oops, I changed that right before copy pasting my code here. In my project I have this as typed, thanks for noticing it though !

Comment: @NickT :   dest.writeList is used for list of type like string,int,boolean etc ??

Comment: Best Answer, Position matters in write and read objects, I have wasted a lot of my time. But your answer save my day. Thanks bro.