# How to pass arrayList of a class object in another activity?

Tags: android

```
ArrayList <Car> CarList = new ArrayList<Car>();  
Car carItems= new Car(carno, cartype, date, arriveTime, carcost);   
CarList .add(carItems);
```

Now I want to pass carList through Intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you actually have to make `Car` a Parcelable.

To add it to the Intent, use `putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)`

**Edit**

To get the list in the other activity, do this in `onCreate` or `onNewIntent`:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
ArrayList<Car> cars = i.getParcelableArrayListExtra("extraKeyUsedWithPutExtra");
```

Comment: hi how to get that list in another activity?

Comment: I added info on how to get the list from another activty to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For passing the the object:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
ArrayList <Car> CarList = new ArrayList<Car>();  
Car carItems= new Car(carno, cartype, date, arriveTime, carcost);   
CarList.add(carItems); 
bundle.putSerializable("carList",carList);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

For retrieving:

```
ArrayList <Car> CarList = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("carList");
```

Make sure `Car` is serializable:

```
public class Car implements Serializable {

}
```

Comment: It show error as  The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<Car>)

Comment: Have you made your `Car` class implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

Comment: public class Car implements Parcelable and I bave implemented public int describeContents(), public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)

Answer (score 0):

Make it parcleable, pretty easy.

Have a look on this posting: [Arraylist in parcelable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704747/arraylist-in-parcelable-object)

Comment: Yes but I want to pass carList through Intent.

Comment: An ArrayList full of Objects can be put into any parcel using: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeTypedList(java.util.List<T>)