# Reading ArrayList in Parcelable

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable

I have a class called SuperMedia that implements Parcelable. One of the fields of the class is an ArrayList children. When I create a Bundle and try to pass a "SuperMedia" object from one activity to another, all the fields get passed fine with the exception of the ArrayList "children" which just shows up as being empty every time.

In my first Activity I do:

```
 Bundle a = new Bundle();
 a.putParcelable("media",media); //media is an object of type "SuperMedia" and all the "children" have been initialized and added to the array
 final Intent i = new Intent("com.tv.video.subcategories");
 i.putExtra("subcategories", a);
```

On my Second Activity I do:

```
  Intent i = getIntent();
  Bundle secondBun = i.getBundleExtra("subcategories");
  SuperMedia media = secondBun.getParcelable("media"); //For some reason the ArrayList"children" field shows up as empty.
```

Im not sure why this is happening. If anybody can guide me on the right path that would be greatly appreciated. Below is my SuperMedia class btw.

```
public class SuperMedia implements Parcelable{

public URI mthumb;
public String mTitle;
public ArrayList<SuperMedia> children = new ArrayList(); 

public SuperMedia(URI thumb, String title) {
    this.mthumb = thumb;
    this.mTitle = title;
}


@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dest.writeString(mTitle);
    dest.writeString(mthumb.toString());
    dest.writeTypedList(children);

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<SuperMedia> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SuperMedia>() {
    public SuperMedia createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new SuperMedia(in);
    }

    public SuperMedia[] newArray(int size) {
        return new SuperMedia[size];
    }
};

private SuperMedia(Parcel in) {
    mTitle = in.readString();
    try {
        mthumb = new URI(in.readString());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    in.readTypedList(children, SuperMedia.CREATOR);

}

public SuperMedia(){

}
```

}

Comment: `children` contains instance of `SuperMedia`? or are there descendants of it?

Comment: @njzk2 It contains descendants

Comment: then it cannot work, as the SuperMedia.CREATOR does not know how to unparcel these.

Comment: Your code seems to should work. I'm not sure, but try to change `public ArrayList<SuperMedia> children = new ArrayList();` to `public List<SuperMedia> children = new ArrayList(); `.

Comment: @erakitin: this does not change anything as ArrayList is a List. Also, the actual issue here is that `SuperMedia implements Parcelable`, but that does not work for anything `extends SuperMedia`, because the `SuperMedia.CREATOR` only can call `new SuperMedia(in)`

Comment: @njzk2 I tried downcasting, and my child class "Subcategory" and overwrote all the Parcelable methods, but in the childClass doing "in.readTypedList(children, Subcategory.CREATOR)" gives me an error

Comment: yes, because your list is still type `List<SuperMedia>` isn't it?

Comment: (Parcelable is far from optimal/obvious once it comes to inheritance. In most cases I would consider not pass the object, but a reference to a database entry, or something like that)

Comment: You have to read in same order as write and that's what's really wrong.  Not the serializable answer.

Comment: @danny117 I was doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want simply pass object through intent then you can make  SuperMedia Serializable no need to Parcelable.

```
public class SuperMedia implements Serializable{...}
```

put it as

`Bundle a = new Bundle();
 a.putSerializable("media",media);`

and we get it as.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle secondBun = i.getBundleExtra("subcategories");
SuperMedia media = (SuperMedia)secondBun.getSerializable("media");
```

if you really needed Parcelable then may it help you.
[Arraylist in parcelable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704747/arraylist-in-parcelable-object)

Comment: Doesn't Parcelable and Serializable do the same thing? My issue is that my arrayList "children" always shows up as empty on the second activity after I pass it

Comment: @Pradeep Parcelable is much faster and more optimized for IPC, which is why it is recommended by android. (People don't just go around adding new ways of doing the same thing just for the thrill of messing with people's head)

Comment: @PradeepYaduvanshy : however, given the ease of use of Serializable compared to Parcelable, in this case it can be a good alternative, if there are many descendants of SuperMedia

Comment: @PradeepYaduvanshy Implementing Serializable rather than Parcelable solved the problem. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use Bundle's putParcellableArrayList for storing SuperMedia object

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putParcelableArrayList("media", "media");
```

and for restroring

```
getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("media");
```

This way will ensure bundle save your list objects as implemented in parcelable instance.
Also, be aware of using only ArrayList, other List subclasses not supported.

Comment: it has to be args.putParcelable because media is an object, not an ArrayList.